# Не работает счетчик

Tags: ruby

Сразу прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, пишу программы для себя\ради обучения \, решил написать тест.Cобственно в кейсе не засчитывает ответ

```
    count=0

puts "Здравствуйте,
Далее вы пройдете тест на ревность.
Тест содержит 12 вопросов. Отвечайте Да\\Нет"


questions = ["Если ваш партнер бросает взгляд на незнакомую женщину, вы устраиваете ему скандал прямо на улице?",
"Если ваш партнер опаздывает на ужин, вы уверены, что он был с другой?",
"Вы расспрашиваете его о работе, о коллегах?",
"Вы считаете, что каждую свободную минуту должны проводить вместе?",
"Он для вас — свет в окошке?",
"Случается ли вам проверять его корреспонденцию и рыться в его вещах?",
"Чем чаще он говорит о своих чувствах, тем меньше вы верите?",
"Вы хотите, чтобы он интересовался только тем, чем интересуетесь вы?",
"Вы всегда спрашиваете у него, куда он ходит и с кем встречается?",
"Если вы на него обижены, то молчите по нескольку дней?",
"Вас мучают мысли о его бывшей возлюбленной?",
"Он утверждает, что не ревнует вас, потому что доверяет. Для вас это означает, что любовь прошла?",
]

questions.each  do |k|
  puts k
  choice=gets.chomp.downcase.encode("UTF-8")
  case choice
    when "да"
      count += 1
    when "нет"
      break
  end
  puts count
end
puts count
puts "Результат:"
if count<5
  puts "Вам совершенно незнакомо чувство ревности. Но тревога и беспокойство могут накапливаться со временем. Вы должны решать волнующие вас проблемы со своим партнером."
elsif count>=5 and count<=9
  puts "Ваша ревность действует на вас мобилизующе, но не она одна управляет вашим поведением. В минуту слабости случается и вам устраивать скандалы. Но, успокоившись, вы понимаете, что для вашей ревности не было никаких оснований."
elsif count>=10
  puts "Вы болезненно ревнивы. Не думайте, что если избранник вас любит, то он автоматически становится вашей собственностью. Вы считаете себя непривлекательной и боитесь, что он бросит вас ради какой нибудь красавицы. Вы ни в чем не уверены, особенно в нем. Задумайтесь над этим, потому что нельзя быть настолько ревнивой и агрессивной, это может привести к конфликтам и даже к разрыву отношений."
end
```

[image]

Comment: ruby 2.3 win. счетчик считает, все работает верно, кроме break который прерывает тест полностью.

Comment: Залил в исходное сообщение скрин вывода.
0 после ответа  это проверка нашего счетчика.
К слову, я тоже удивлен тому, что оно не работает.

Comment: а вы запустите его из системной консоли, а не рубимйновской

Comment: Консоль вовсе не пашет
при вызове ruby test.rb говорит \\"ruby" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
В патче прописал. Результата ноль
Пардон, заработало.
Собственно в чем проблема рубимайна?Почему он не хочет выдавать то что должно быть?
И второй маленьки вопрос, как быть с брейком?На что его можно заменить, чтобы не было потерь в памяти?

Comment: проблема рубимайна в кодировке консоли. просто чудо что он еще кириллицу у вас рисует. с  бряком никак не быть - просто убрать ненужный when (связь его с памятью не уловил)

Comment: Вся соль с кодировкой в строке choice=gets.chomp.downcase.encode("UTF-8")
Просто если модернизировать наш кейс выбором да(увеличиваем счетчик на 1 ), выбором нет(увеличиваем на 0), елсе (введите заново) не будет ли в этом проблемы с памятью?Опять же прошу прощения, с памятью не доводилось работать.Главное ведь, чтобы меньше кушало.

Comment: Если меньше кушало если до фанатизма доводить, то зря выбрали руби. А вообще "увеличиваем на 0" это то же самое что "ничего не увеличиваем". Расход памяти в +=1 копеечный. Тут у вас незачем оптимизировать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42456/discussion-between-qwd666-and-vitidev).

Comment: В скрипте ошибка, в break нужен next. После исправления в Ruby 2.2.4 в Mac OS X скрипт отрабатывает как надо.

Comment: Спасибо!
проблема решена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процитирую  vitidev'a "проблема рубимайна в кодировке консоли. просто чудо что он еще кириллицу у вас рисует. с бряком никак не быть - просто убрать ненужный when"